# BeagleBone Black doesn't connect via Ethernet on laptop

Tags: ubuntu, ethernet

I have a BeagleBone Black board connected to my laptop with only a serial connection and the Ethernet cable, and powered by the 5mm jack. The serial connection works fine, I can login at any time, but I can't do it over the Ethernet connection. Ubuntu 14.04 is running on my laptop.

The output of `ifconfig` on the laptop's side is:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:26:9e:54:39:db  
          inet6 addr: fe80::226:9eff:fe54:39db/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:30 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1102 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12400 (12.4 KB)  TX bytes:225290 (225.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:7615 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7615 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:764895 (764.8 KB)  TX bytes:764895 (764.8 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0c:ee:e6:80:75:e4  
          inet addr:10.17.255.177  Bcast:10.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::eee:e6ff:fe80:75e4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:161592 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:57437
          TX packets:133489 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:185045013 (185.0 MB)  TX bytes:15021821 (15.0 MB)
          Interrupt:16
```

on the BB's side though serial communication:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:59:AF:5C:D1:3E                         
          inet addr:169.254.28.162  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0     
          inet6 addr: fe80::9259:afff:fe5c:d13e/64 Scope:Link                   
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1                    
          RX packets:535 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                  
          TX packets:41 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000                                          
          RX bytes:111890 (109.2 KiB)  TX bytes:12586 (12.2 KiB)                
          Interrupt:56                                                          

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback                                             
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0                                   
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host                                        
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1                              
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                    
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0                                             
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)                                

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 76:09:06:0A:D5:77                         
          inet addr:192.168.7.2  Bcast:192.168.7.3  Mask:255.255.255.252        
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1                            
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                    
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                  
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000                                          
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

and if I run `route -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.17.255.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.17.240.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
```

I can't see my board connected either on eth1 or similar, nor can I load into the BeagleBone without the USB or serial connection.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Do you want to connect via IPv6 or IPv4? because your computer does not have an IPv4 address set in eth0.

Comment: I don't know really the difference for a BB.

Comment: Try adding an IPv4 address in the 169.254.0.0 network to your PC's eth0 and see if your PC can now communicate with your BB.

Comment: It didn't work :(

Comment: Does the connection between your BB and your PC go through a router/hub or have you used a ethernet cable to statblish a direct connection between both machines? if you have used the cable to connect both machines, it must be crossover, otherwise it won't work. If this is not the case both machines are connected to a router, you should be able to ping its address from both machines, can you do that?